# Resolving lint errors when registering the ChartJS gradient plugin?

Tags: javascript, typescript, chart.js

Attempting to import and register the [chart.js gradient plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-gradient) in [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ab2mmj?file=index.ts) and it produces the below Typescript linting error when declaring the plugin this.

```
  plugins: {
    gradient,
  },
```

This is the error.

```
Type '{ gradient: Plugin<keyof ChartTypeRegistry, AnyObject>; }' is not assignable to type 'Plugin<keyof ChartTypeRegistry, AnyObject>[]'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'gradient' does not exist in type 'Plugin<keyof ChartTypeRegistry, AnyObject>[]'.(2322)
index.d.ts(3819, 3): The expected type comes from property 'plugins' which is declared here on type 'ChartConfiguration<keyof ChartTypeRegistry, (number | [number, number] | Point | BubbleDataPoint)[], unknown>'
(property) gradient: Plugin<keyof ChartTypeRegistry, AnyObject>
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: `plugins` at the top level of the configuration object should be an array, enumerating the [inline plugins](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#using-plugins). So in your case it should be `plugins: [gradient]`. You also have an object `plugins: {... }`, but that's under `options`, when each of the declared or registered plugins, as well as the default ones, like `title`, `tooltip`, etc., may receive their options.

Comment: @kikon thanks!  I added a note about the plugin registration to the repository https://github.com/kurkle/chartjs-plugin-gradient/issues/53